# Didn't return all hard links to a file

Tags: find, inode

I failed to get all hard links to a file with `find / -inum *`.

```
linux-5.5.9$ ls -lai
total 856
1048577 drwxrwxr-x  24 root root   4096 Mar 12 14:18 .

linux-5.5.9$ sudo find / -inum 1048577
/home/public/linux-5.5.9
```

`ls -lai` shows the file `.` has 24 hard links, but `find / -inum 1048577` only returns one.

The details of my machine,

```
$ uname -a
Linux jmu-cs-ubuntu 4.15.0-54-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 24 10:55:24 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: How is it related to Ubuntu?

Comment: @Pilot6, I am working on Ubuntu. Should I post it on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @guiverc, thx for the mention. I just updated my question `Linux jmu-cs-ubuntu 4.15.0-54-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 24 10:55:24 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: That doesn't tell us your release, only that you're using an out-dated un-patched kernel from June 2019 and may not have updated/upgraded your system since then.

Comment: @guiverc It rally doesn't matter. It can be 18.04, but that makes no difference in this case.

Comment: A kernel that old implies Linux Mint 19.1 to me @Pilot6 and not Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you search for hardlinks to an inode which represents a directory, I assume the number of hardlinks are the result of subdirectories, where their hardlinks represent `subdirectory/..`. `.` and `..` directory-entries are normally not searched by the find command.

Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Hard-Links

```
Test: -inum n

File has inode number n. The ‘+’ and ‘-’ qualifiers also work, though these
are rarely useful. Much of the time it is easier to use ‘-samefile’ rather than
this option. 

You can also search for files that have a certain number of links, with ‘-links’.
Directories normally have at least two hard links; their . entry is the second one.
If they have subdirectories, each of those also has a hard link called .. to its
parent directory. The . and .. directory entries are not normally searched unless
they are mentioned on the find command line.
```